# Is there any way to access an internal Node.js module?

Tags: node.js

By "internal" I mean something like `internal/process/esm_loader`.

I've tried `process`, `require('module')` but cannot find a way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can by starting node with the `--expose-internals` option. There is no documented API so using internal modules may not continue to work from one nodejs release to another.